# How to create ListView with ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Tags: android, listview

I try to use [ActionBar-PullToRefresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh). I create simple `ListView` and program works fine with this lib. But i dont know how to implement such sing: when You are pulling down, `ListView` is pulling down too such is in iOS apps.

Comment: Are you required to use this library? If not you can use GestureListener and update the list view when a swipe down gesture is performed

Comment: Instead of using a 3rd party, look at the `SwipeRefreshLayout` recently added to Android. Here's a tutorial on how to add it to a `ListView`: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-swiperefreshlayout-tutorial.html. It's really easy to implement :-)